# Proper way to call a model constant in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, php, model, class

I have the class below:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Somemodel extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    const SOME_CONST = 'constant_text';   
}
```

What is the proper and correct way to call the constant in another class?
Like this:

```
$class = Mage::getModel('company_model/somemodel');
echo $class::SOME_CONST;
```

Or like this:

```
echo Company_Module_Model_Somemodel::SOME_CONST;
```

Can you explain why is the one better than other? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo Company_Module_Model_Somemodel::SOME_CONST;
```

This one is way to go because Magento uses an autoloader and your class will be autoloaded by name

For further detail please check the reference link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792370/proper-way-to-handle-model-constants-in-magento

**I hope this will help**

Answer (score 0):

You can call the constant as :

```
class ClassName {
    const CONSTANTNAME = 'ConstantValue';
}
```

Now you can call this `constant` as `echo ClassName::CONSTANTNAME`.